# Quotation goes wrong in ShareLaTeX

Tags: punctuation, sharelatex

I'm writing my thesis with the help of ShareLatex. However 25% of the time my quotation goes wrong. I think I am quoting correctly, using: `hello world' and ``hello world". And most of the time this results in good quotations. However sometimes this happens:

[image: The ugly quotation]

My code is the following:

``rich menu of alternative possibilities within qualitative research"\citep{patton1990qualitative}

I really don't understand why this is happening and it is super ugly.

Can someone help me with this?

Cheers!

Comment: Load package `csquotes` and do `\enquote{This is enquoted text}`. You can also nest it.

Comment: I don't understand. Your screenshot looks perfectly normal, what did you expect, what is ugly?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. you are absolutely right, I didn't attach the correct picture...

Comment: Perhaps you're using `"`, try `''` (two times `'`).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It worked! Can't believe I didn't think of this myself, but thanks a lot!

Comment: @user3481742 The `\cite` command should not be attached to the quotes (to be typed `''` as two separate apostrophes); have a space in between: `research'' \citep{patton1990qualitative}`. To the contrary, you seem to have a space before the following `\footnote`, which is wrong. Note: I used a hard space in order to keep the code together, don't do it yourself; if you want to avoid a line break, use `~`: `research''~\citep{patton1990qualitative}`

Answer (score 1):

The input you show is incorrect (although it normally works by accident, it should be

```
``hello world''
```

not

```
``hello world"
```

with two `'` not a `"`

Without a full example, hard to say exactly why you are getting a straight quote in the output